# what kind of property names can i have ?

Tags: c#, properties

can we have property names like `$ref #schema` ? If so, how ? If not why not ?
I am actually to do something like this

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.$ref = somevlaue;
```

but I can't do that?

Also , how do I workaround the fact that keywords can't be property names?

Comment: What's the point of having `$` and `#` in your property names anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
public string @class {get; set;}
```

for using keywords as variable names. For more information you can see the rules for [Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Since you are mainly interested in the `ExpandoObject`, a workaround would be to directly set and/or retrieve those property names by casting the ExpandoObject to an `IDictionary<string, Object>`:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = (IDictionary<string, Object>)d;
dict["$ref"] = "haha!";
```

Comment: this is what i do normally , any other way ?

Comment: no - the C# compiler will not allow you to compile successfully using invalid property names as detailed by the language specification (section 2.4.2), i.e. containing `$`

Answer (score 3):

The language has the guideline of acceptable chars of name. In your case you can try to use `@ref`.